# SPARQL: Bound variable doesn't work in union

Tags: sparql, wikidata

It's unclear to me why this variable (`?entity`) works in one `UNION` but not in the other (desired result is `Q8740` in `val` column for `wikidata-id`):

```
SELECT ?propLabel ?val WHERE {
  BIND(wd:Q8740 as ?entity)
  {
    BIND(?entity AS ?valUrl)
    BIND("n/a" AS ?propUrl)
    BIND("name"@en AS ?propLabel)
    ?entity rdfs:label ?val.
    FILTER((LANG(?val)) = "en")

# wikidata-id
  } UNION {
#   BIND(?entity as ?val) **this doesn't work**
    BIND(wd:Q8740 AS ?val)
    BIND("wikidata-id" AS ?propLabel)
  }

# description
  } UNION {
    BIND(?entity AS ?valUrl) - **but here, ?entity works fine!**
    BIND("description"@en AS ?propLabel)
    OPTIONAL { ?entity schema:description ?val. }
    FILTER((LANG(?val)) = "en")
  }
}
```

Nothing appears in the `val` column for `wikidata-id` unless I 'manually' specify the entity in question, but ONLY in that one `UNION`...?

Comment: https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics#UNIONs

Comment: Hm, the thing that confuses me is that I have a bunch of other `UNION`s that DO use `?entity` in them just fine (added above), so it doesn't seem like a scope problem? Also I don't think I understand your `?entity ^schema...` idea :o

Comment: Add something like `OPTIONAL {?entity a []}` to the 2nd `UNION`.

Comment: Please also paste link to the full query, perhaps there are other ways to get what you need.